# logistic regression and numpy: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression, array-broadcasting

Machine learning beginner here.
In python 3.7, I keep getting this error when trying to run numpy.optimize's `fmin_tnc`.
I know this type of question has been asked several times, but despite having checked my matrix dimensions and the code several times, I can't find my mistake.

Here is the function:

```py
def compute_cost(theta, X, y, lambda_):
    m = len(y)
    mask = np.eye(len(theta))
    mask[0,0] = 0

    hypo = sigmoid(X @ theta)
    func = y.T @ np.log(hypo) + (1-y.T) @ np.log(1-hypo)
    cost = -1/m * func
    reg_cost = cost + lambda_/(2*m) * (mask@theta).T @ (mask@theta)

    grad = 1/m * X.T@(hypo-y) + lambda_/m * (mask@theta)

    return reg_cost.item(), grad
```

Here are my dimensions:

```
X: (118, 3)
y: (118, 1)
theta: (3, 1)
```

The function call,

```py
initial_theta = np.zeros((3,1))
lambda_ = 1

thetopt, nfeval, rc = opt.fmin_tnc(
    func=compute_cost, 
    x0=initial_theta, 
    args=(X, y, 1)
)
```

And the error.

```
File "<ipython-input-21-f422f885412a>", line 16, in compute_cost
    grad = 1/m * X.T@(hypo-y) + lambda_/m * (mask@theta)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,118) (3,)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which term has shape (3,118) and which (3,)?  `X.T` looks like it would be (3,118).  I don't see the code for the `compute_cost` function.

Comment: @hpaulj my bad, wrong code indeed, I edited the question with the compute_cost function

Comment: Yes `X.T` is the (3,118) one. I defined my `theta` as (3,1) in `np.zeros((3,1))` so no idea where this (3,) is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scipy.optimize.tnc, fmin_tnc function calls to _minimize_tnc, which seems to do the heavy lifting. In this function, almost the first thing it does (line 348) it to flatten x0:

```
x0 = asfarray(x0).flatten()
```

So what you need to do, is to reshape it in your function. Just add this line in the begging of your compute_cost function:

```
theta = theta.reshape((3, 1))
```